# How do I know if an element is on the screen?

Tags: javascript, extjs, element

In the viewport is shown certain amount of elements that are visible and others that are not because of the scroll displacement. Certanly the properties visible/hide does not depends on the viewport's visible elements on the sreen. I did not find any ExtJS method in order to know if an element is shown in the viewport or not.

The natural path leads me on the measures of viewport and the positions of a particular element to find but I would like to exhaust the possibilities of the ExtJS framework first, is there any?

> Requirements:
>   **ExtJS 6.2.0**

Answer (score 0):

This is a way without ExtJS, where *el* is the element to evaluate and *ctr* is the container of the element

```
elementStateInScrolling= function (el,ctr){
    el=el.el; 
    ctr=ctr.el;
    let containerTop, containerBottom, elemTop, elemBottom;

    //Portion visible of the container
    containerTop = ctr.getY();
    containerBottom = containerTop + ctr.getHeight();
    //Boundaries of the element
    elemTop = el.getY();
    elemBottom = elemTop + el.getHeight();
    //True if the element is completly shown        
    return ((elemBottom <= containerBottom) && (elemTop >= containerTop));
}
```

sources: [Sencha Forum 2012](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?230003-Finding-out-if-an-element-is-hidden-by-scrolling)